# Exclude one particular image from img {display: none; }

Tags: css, image, border

I've added `img {display: none; }` to my style sheet but I'd like to exclude one image (a logo) from that CSS rule as I'd still like my logo to appear on the page. How would I do that?

Comment: Add an ID to it and use that ID to select that particular image.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP fails to understand how basic CSS selectors work.

Answer (score 0):

that particular image

```
<img id="id1"/>
```

CSS:

```
#id1
{
    display:inline-block; ie. other than none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

img:not('#logo'){
display: none;
}